# Cannot read POST array from AJAX call in external PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, post

I've tried every solution I could google, but I can't read the data from a POST array in my external PHP file. Here's the HTML of the text field.

```
    <form>
    <textarea id="comment_text_area" name="comments" rows="5" cols="40">     
    </textarea>
    <label for="comment_text_area">Comment:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="SaveComments()">
    </form>
```

... and the JS function making the AJAX call

```
function save()
{
    var data = document.getElementById("comment_text_area");
    var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr.open('POST', 'save_comments.php', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            alert("Comments saved!");
        }
    }
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

... and the PHP file

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['comments']))
    {
    $data = htmlentities($_POST['comments']);
    $file = "comments.txt";
    file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
    else
    {
    $data = "empty";
    $file = "comments.txt";
    file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
    ?>
```

What I know is working: 
The AJAX call is completing successfully, and the script is being run and "empty" is being written.

Things I have tried:

1. I read that event listener functions should be attached to HTML elements before they are made, which seems counter-intuitive. Made no change.
2. Using

   ```
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   ```

Didn't work. And, based on the research I've done for that, shouldn't that only seem necessary for GET calls? (I need to use POST)

1. Making the POST call synchronous. Nothing changed.

I Know that the name of the element you're passing needs to be what you rely on in the PHP script, but it's not working. I don't want to set form action="" because I don't want redirection, which is why I'm going through AJAX. 
Finally, something I've noticed, it's changing the URL as I click submit, something I would expect from GET. That is GET specific, right? I clearly marked it as POST though.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

P.S. - Please, if it's on the JS side of things, no jQuery. I've avoided it thus far, I'm trying to keep it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a variable to pass in the request not just the value as

```
xhr.send("comments="+data);
```

So that in server side you can retrieve the data by param name.

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked like a charm. I don't know why that has been difficult to find over the internet.